# How to get eclipse libraries compiled on Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-8, compilation

Let me begin with the error I see and then I will explain the case followed by:

```html
<p style="color:red">
EclipseJDTUtil.java:[3,34] cannot access org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject
  bad class file: C:\Users\ram\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\platform\org.eclipse.core.resources\3.15.0\org.eclipse.core.resources-3.15.0.jar(org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
</p>
```

My project has a dependency on ***org.eclipse.jdt.core*** library.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I built my project with JRE8. I used maven plugin to point to the right version at compilation like below.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It has been OK all these days but suddenly from past few days, I see below error. I understand that this library is now available with source compiled on java 11 which is causing issues to my project. But, how is that possible? When the project source is at java 8, the dependencies should not be downloaded for java 11.

I am not in a position to update my whole project to new java version!

What I need is the eclipse libraries compiled on java 8. How should I get them on maven build? What configuration will make it possible?

***Edit 1: (Response to Andreas comment):***

@Andreas: Superb. As you pointed out correctly, it is pulling org.eclipse.core.resources: 3.15.0, as shown in the error. As you suggested I have added version for "resources" like below:

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.resources</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After I maven build I see below error now.

```html
<p style="color:red">
EclipseJDTUtil.java:[8,32] cannot access org.eclipse.core.runtime.IPath
  bad class file: C:\Users\ram\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\platform\org.eclipse.equinox.common\3.15.0\org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.15.0.jar(org/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
</p>
```

I am also attaching Dependency Hierarchy screenshots.

[image]
[image: after adding version for resources]

Comment: Artifact `org.eclipse.jdt.core` version `3.23.0` hasn't changed since 2020-09-14, so it can't have suddenly changed in the past few days. Re-think what you've been doing. Did you perhaps change the version you depend on?

Comment: Did you perhaps change the version you depend on? - which version are you referring to? I didn’t change this in the past couple of months. My latest maven update resulted into these issues. Are you saying that if I do clean and do maven force update artifacts, It should be solved?

Comment: I was referring to `3.23.0`, and I'm saying that the artifacts of that are from 2020-09-14. See for youself: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.23.0/

Comment: No, I changed this version down to 3.18 also but facing the same issue.

Comment: Are they same artifacts available from maven repository also? If so, I should not see this error!!

Comment: Ahh, `org.eclipse.jdt » org.eclipse.jdt.core » 3.23.0` (Sep 16, 2020) depends on `org.eclipse.platform » org.eclipse.core.resources » 3.12.0` (Oct 17, 2017), but the error message shows that you seem to have gotten `org.eclipse.platform » org.eclipse.core.resources » 3.15.0` (Jun 15, 2021). You might need to force that back to version `3.12.0`.

Comment: @Andreas: You are right. I tried your suggestion. Added details in Edit.

Comment: Eclipse changed to use Java 11. You might want to do that, too.

Comment: @Andreas: Based on your suggestion, I have managed to control the dependency versions. If you post it as answer, I will be able to accept it as a possible solution for the people in need. Thanks

Comment: @Gana Nah, but feel free to go ahead and self-answer your question.

Comment: The problem is, that eclipse is using version ranges instead of fixed versions in their dependencies. After switching to Java 11 they did not change their versions to something higher than the used version ranges to not created conflicts between Java <11 and >=11 projects. Short: They broke nearly all build systems that still use Java <11 and depend on such eclipse projects (In my case they broke the usage of Hibernate Tools). They even have different certificates in their dependencies which causes other exceptions. I downgraded org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.equinox.common to 3.14.100

Comment: Have faced the same problem recently, actually `org.eclipse.jdt > org.eclipse.jdt.core` depends on other eclipse artifacts of `org.eclipse.platform`. Now, there's no update in the `org.eclipse.jdt.core > 3.23.0`  but there is update in artifacts of `org.eclipse.platform` like `org.eclipse.equinox.common, org.eclipse.core.runtime, etc.` and I guess this artifacts are compiled using java 11 which basically causing the issue. So added exclusions for these artifacts in the dependency of `org.eclipse.jdt.core` & added dependency for the excluded artifacts with older versions in pom.xml, it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a very similar issue. Managed to get it working again by downgrading from

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.27.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

(which worked fine under java 8 up to a few weeks ago) to:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

which seems to still work fine with java 8, at least for the AST functionality I'm using in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of [@KC_911723](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039780/how-to-get-eclipse-libraries-compiled-on-java-8#comment121463492_68039780) and [@grubi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68039780/how-to-get-eclipse-libraries-compiled-on-java-8#comment120578608_68039780) you can use this configuration:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.common</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.equinox.common</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.100</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

or use this gradle configuration:

```
dependencies {
    implementation ('org.eclipse.jdt:org.eclipse.jdt.core:3.23.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.platform', module: 'org.eclipse.core.runtime'
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.platform', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.common'
    }
    implementation ('org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.core.runtime:3.13.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.eclipse.platform', module: 'org.eclipse.equinox.common'
    }
    implementation 'org.eclipse.platform:org.eclipse.equinox.common:3.14.100'
}
```